# Why is my layout/css different when I loop in PHP vs when I just use HTML with no loop

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have boxes which display side by side in a 50% width fashion.
And they display fine when I just use regular HTML to display.

```
<div class="superbox-list">
  <img src="img/superbox/superbox-thumb-3.jpg" class="superbox-img">
</div>
<div class="superbox-list">
  <img src="img/superbox/superbox-thumb-4.jpg" class="superbox-img">
</div>
```

However when I loop in PHP / Laravel.  Suddenly it doesnt obey the css rules???

```
@foreach($posts as $p)
    <div class="superbox-list">
      <img src="img/superbox/superbox-thumb-3.jpg" class="superbox-img">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

When I use a loop to display these boxes, somehow the 50% rule gets broken for some reason, and they display one after the other , without being side by side.  So theres empty space next to each image where there should just be the next image.  Instead its empty, and its as if the div is just ignoring the rules and sizing to 100%???

What the hell is going on her?

EDIT : FIXED by doing this?? No idea why this should/would matter, but it did.

```
@foreach($posts as $p)<div class="superbox-list"><img src="img/superbox/superbox-thumb-3.jpg" class="superbox-img"></div>@endforeach
```

Comment: You code looks fine to me, at a guess, I would say you have mistyped a quote or double quote somewhere, and its effecting the html output. My first step would be to view html source and look at the rendered output for any errors.

Comment: Everything looks fine.....but I figured it out.  For some reason, I cant have any spaces between the boxes.  So if I just echo it out a continuous string it works.  Bizarre, never seen anything like this in the 10 years I've been developing.

Comment: Looks fine, although in your HTML example you are using `thumb-3` and `thumb-4`, whereas in your loop you are only using `thumb-3`.

Comment: Yeah that doesnt matter, that was just for example purposes.  Im using values from the database of course.  BUt yeah....I solved it in my edit.  Just removed all spaces and it worked.  which is completely bizarre, and I honestly have literaly no idea why it worked or should/would matter.  Seriously never seen anything this bizarre ever

Comment: because  the loop was creating extra spaces

Comment: Yes, but why would that matter?  When I just did it in HTML it didnt matter. If I manually displayed them,  I could have 200 spaces between each div and it would still display fine.  Its only when I used PHP that the spaces mattered.  Is this because php actually echos a hidden character or something as a space?